# macro to uncheck ActiveX checkbox but not grayed out?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro on a command button (not an ActiveX), that uncheck ActiveX checkboxes and clear specific cells but some checkboxes are grayed out with checked (not disabled).

They don't have any values even True or False.

I don't see any mistakes in my code.

```
Sub reset_checkbox()
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("L3:L12", "L14:L19").value = False
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("L20:L25", "L13").ClearContents
End Sub
```

Comment: Note that `Range("L3:L12", "L14:L19")` actually includes `L13`. And `Range("L20:L25", "L13")` includes `L14:L19`. You may want `"Range("L3:L12,L14:19")`, with the comma *inside* the quotes.

Comment: Yes, that was what I exactly wanted. Thanks a lot !